# Why is this ImageView not being released?

Tags: ios, ipad, memory, uiview

i have a splash page that is displayed on app startup that my client wants me to keep visible for x amount of time. Everything is working great except the image is never released?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    NSString *fileLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"splash_page" ofType:@"png"];

    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileLocation];
    UIImage *launchImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    [imageData release], imageData = nil;

    UIImageView *launchImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:launchImage];
    launchImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 
        0, 
        [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width , 
        [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
    launchImageView.tag = 121;
    [launchImage release], launchImage = nil;

    [self.window addSubview:launchImageView];
    [launchImageView release], launchImage = nil;   

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    
    [self performSelector:@selector(initApp) withObject:nil afterDelay:kInitDelay];

    return YES;
}

- (void)initApp
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

    UIImageView *launchImageView = (UIImageView*)[self.window viewWithTag:121];
    [launchImageView removeFromSuperview];

    RootNavController *navController = [[RootNavController alloc] initRootController];
    self.rootNavController = navController;
    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
    [navController release], navController = nil;
}
```

It is my understanding that removeFromSuperview calls release on the view so this should be released however i can still see a Malloc of 524kb in Intruments Object Allocation tool which im sure is the image. Responsible Library = libRIP.A.dylib and the Responsible Caller ripl_Create.

If i comment out the splash page code and launch the NavController directly i dont have that 524kb.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you comment out just the `[self.window addSubview:launchImageView]` line, does it still have that 524kb? Have you checked to be sure `[self.window viewWithTag:121]` actually is returning the image view and not nil for some reason?

Comment: If you do a 'Simulate Memory Warning' from the Hardware menu on the simulator does the memory go away? I'm thinking UIKit might be caching it for future use until the memory is needed

Comment: @Anomie If i comment out that line i still have the 524kb because even though im not adding it to the window i am still initializing it. If i comment out the whole section starting at setting the string then the 524kb no longer shows up obv. Also i am printing out the address for launchImageView right after initializing it and after getting it again with viewWithTag and its pointing to the same address?

Comment: @Cory i also thought it might be caching which is why i ended up using the round about method of setting the image instead of using imageNamed. However even after i simulate a memory warning it is not released?

Comment: @HenryH: How about if you completely remove the allocation of `launchImageView` (just initialize the variable to nil instead, and also skipping the `addSubview` if necessary)? Or the same for `launchImage`?

Comment: @Anomie this is the line that is causing the 524kb allocation:      NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileLocation]; If i comment it out no 524kb.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use the Default.png as your splash screen? Renaming your "Splash_page.png" to "Default.png" will automatically show the splash page on load and then just add UIImageView (with Default.png) to the MainWindow and after x time launch your rootViewController.